# MetaMask DeepLink: AppStore opens before MetaMask is opened, and the deeplink is not opened in MetaMask

Tags: deep-linking, metamask

I am trying to setup deep link for MetaMask. It works on my device (iPhone 13) but on some other devices (iPhone with unknown build) it would trigger in the following flow:

1. The user click the link
2. The App Store page opens
3. The MetaMask opens but stay in the wallet page, not in browser page

Is there any fix for this one? Both devices are using the latest version of MetaMask.